# Need a formula to delete after comparison in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, comparison

I have two Excel sheets.

First Excel has list of 89000+ user names and their storage space which I generated.

Second Excel has list of 2700+ user names whose storage I have to fill.

I have tried online solutions like formulas of if is error
and some conditional.

They are giving the expected results.

Can anyone please reply with a formula which will compare 2700+ users with 89000+ users so, I can get the 2700+ users Storage metrics ?

```
Assume :
Column A has 89000+ user names
Column B has Storage of 89000+ users respectively
Column C has 2700+ user names.
```

Note : you can change the order of columns if it will give the answer.

I request the help of this community as this is important.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the usernames are unique, and the column layout is the same as described above in a single sheet, in cell D1 enter `=VLOOKUP(C:C, A:B, 2, FALSE)` (and  press ctrl+shift+enter if not in Office365).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Can you briefly explain how does this formula work ? I understood some but I have used VLOOKUP without understanding it. C:C - All C, A:B is ? Considering A1,B1(example) as one.
Why is 2 used ?

I know I am asking for more, but your explanation would be very much appreciated.
God Bless.

Comment: Your best bet to understand this is to look up array formulas (sometimes called CSE formulas because of the ctrl+shift+enter bit) - basically where normal formulas return a single value, these formulas output multiple values, an array.

Comment: In this case, `A:B` refers to the whole of columns A and B, and `C:C` for column C (to refer to a whole row you can use `1:1`)

Comment: The first 2 arguments in the vlookup formula are the lookup value and the table array - in other words, what are we looking for and where are we looking for it. The second question is a simple one, we're looking at columns A and B to contain our value and it's matching result. However in the first argument, instead of asking it to look for one value we've given it the whole of column C to look for, ensuring we'll get a whole column of answers as it works through each cell in column C.

Comment: Hope that clarifies things a bit for you, as I mentioned I don't know your current level of fluency in excel but do have a quick Google into vlookup formulas and array formulas, both are extremely powerful (even when not used together)

Comment: I'm sorry I should have mentioned in reply to your original question, the 2 is used because the result we want is in the 2nd column of the table array we're looking in (in this case `A:B`)